# How can I access Google Docs through my j2me application?

Tags: java-me, google-docs-api

Can anybody tell me how can I access Google Docs through my j2me app?

Is there any api? If so, can you link me it?

Answer (score 1):

Let me google that for you: [Google Docs Java API](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_java.html)

Comment: @Hitendra Not to embarrass you, but you should mark applicable answers as accepted if they solve your problem.

Comment: @scriptHero I don't see nagging him about a lame answer 5 years later paying off